# Unlabeled vs unstructured data

Tags: machine-learning

Trying to understand the difference between unlabeled and unstructured data. Are they synonyms?

From my understanding, unlabeled data is data that does highlight the target variable. Unstructured data is just raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unstructured data - means that it is not structured in a table-like form. Some examples for unstructured data are - images, text, audio.

Unlabeled data means that you don’t have labels and you should use unsupervised methods to deal with this problem.